# xmonad startup hook for focusOnMouseMove not working

Tags: xmonad

I am trying to give focus to a window whenever the cursor moves on it.

Use case:

1. window A focused by the cursor
2. user moves focus with the keyboard
3. user moves the mouse and expects the window below the cursor to activate

Instead of 3, I am required to move the cursor to *another* window, then back.

[This exists](http://code.haskell.org/~sjanssen/xmonad-web/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Actions-UpdateFocus.html), and seems to do exactly what I want. I can't make it work.

[Here is what I have](https://github.com/fleutot/.xmonad/blob/test_focusOnMouseMove/xmonad.hs), see rows 121 and 122, or see the diff in case it's easier (there are a couple changes with indentation, I leave it here just to be sure not to remove anything relevant):

```
@@ -1,5 +1,6 @@
 import XMonad hiding ((|||))
 import XMonad.Actions.RotSlaves
+import XMonad.Actions.UpdateFocus
 import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog
 import XMonad.Hooks.EwmhDesktops
 import XMonad.Hooks.ManageDocks
@@ -111,12 +112,14 @@ myKeys =
          , (f, m) <- [(W.view, 0), (W.shift, shiftMask)]]

 main = do
-    xmproc <- spawnPipe "/usr/bin/xmobar ~/.xmonad/.xmobarrc -x 0"
-    --xmproc <- spawnPipe "~/.cabal/bin/xmobar ~/.xmonad/.xmobarrc -x 1"
-    xmonad $ withUrgencyHook NoUrgencyHook
-           $ defaultConfig {
+  xmproc <- spawnPipe "/usr/bin/xmobar ~/.xmonad/.xmobarrc -x 0"
+  xmonad
+    $ withUrgencyHook NoUrgencyHook
+    $ defaultConfig {
         workspaces = myWorkspaces
         , terminal = "gnome-terminal"
+        , startupHook = adjustEventInput
+        , handleEventHook = focusOnMouseMove
         , manageHook = myManageHook <+> manageHook defaultConfig
         , layoutHook = avoidStruts $ smartBorders $ myLayout
         , logHook = dynamicLogWithPP xmobarPP
```

`xmonad` version 0.12. I've tried not only `mod+q`, but also logging out and in.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the pointer movement mask that `focusOnMouseMove` used is no longer implemented that way, which makes this contribution obsolete.

That is the answer I got on IRC:

Instead of setting up the startupHook, try to update the masks

```
, rootMask = rootMask defaultConfig .|. pointerMotionMask
, clientMask = clientMask defaultConfig .|. pointerMotionMask
```

That didn't work for me, but hey, good luck if someone else wants to try it.